# Passing function of function to timeit getting NameError

Tags: python

I want to time three similar functions with timeit. I have written this code, but I don't understand what's is happening when I am passing a function to the test function.

```
def f0(x,  y,  z):
#some code here

def f1(x,  y,  z):
#a slighty similar function


def f2(x, y, z):
#still another similar function



def test(name):
    x=100
    y=100
    z=100
    res=name(x,y,z)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("test(f0)", setup="from __main__ import test"))
```

The error I got is:

```
NameError: global name 'f0' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import *all* global names mentioned in the test:

```
print(timeit.timeit("test(f0)", setup="from __main__ import test, f0"))
```

The line `test(f0)` needs to look up `f0` too, not just `test()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `f0` as well, like this

```
print(timeit.timeit("test(f0)", setup="from __main__ import test, f0"))
```